# java script in link href="javascript:alert(1)"

Tags: xss, javascript, html

In an app I am testing they allow to input a domain name, store it, and when they print it on the browser they concatenate "http://" at the beginning of the domain. So, if you input "google.com", then they create a link like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com"> google </a>
```

So, if you try to input "javascript:alert(1)", the link would be

```
<a href="http://javascript:alert(1)"> google </a>
```

If they would not concatenate the "http://" at the beginning, that javascript would execute when the link is clicked. So, we can be sure that that is 100% safe from XSS because they always concatenate the "http://" at the beginning?

Thanks!
**Note: If you input quotes, they encode them as \u003ca**

Comment: In this case that would not work because they encode quotes as \u003ca

Comment: What if I encode **"** with **%22** ?

Comment: @Rahul I thnik it would just be displayed as " but not executed

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this method would be safe from XSS. This type of vulnerability sounds like a typical case of [Reflected XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Reflected_Cross_site_scripting_(OTG-INPVAL-001)). If you would escape the `href` tag with some `"` you can enter a XSS code. Your link would look like this if you enter `foo.at"><script>alert(81)</script>"page=1` into the input field ->

```
<a href="http://foo.at"><script>alert(81)</script>"page=1">google </a>
```

I would suggest to use a filter on the website which converts all special chars to an other format. Like [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php) in php.

Comment: with this note  Note: If you input quotes, they encode them as \u003ca, I meant you cannot do that specifically